# Installing Nightmare.js on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, nightmare

My app needs installing nightmare.js which includes electron browser for web scraping. I followed this article https://medium.com/@johann.pardanaud/running-electron-on-heroku-db3866a690a3 but there are no results. So how can I install Nightmare.js with electon in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [Nightmare Heroku Example](https://github.com/kireerik/nightmare-heroku-example#getting-started) project I include easy to follow step by step instructions about [how to set up a Heroku app with Nightmare](https://github.com/kireerik/nightmare-heroku-example#set-up-heroku-app).

Comment: Thanks. I've already installed my app to the Heroku using this instruction: [a setup for nightmarejs on heroku](https://github.com/oscarmorrison/nightmare-heroku)